# "PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script"

Tags: init.d

I'm trying to create an init script for a web application I want to run on system start up. Looking through the skeleton script provided by my OS (`/etc/init.d/skeleton`), I saw this:

```
# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

What does this mean? If I want `/usr/bin` included in the path, do I have to do something to ensure that `mountnfs.sh` gets run first?

And where is `mountnfs.sh` located? I don't see it in my `init.d` directory.

Comment: what kind of web application? static content? java? ruby? python?

Comment: @dawud I'm using Rails. That's kind of beside the point though, this is something that could be applicable to any init script.

Comment: Not necessarily. You might not need an `init` script at all. Your web server may have one already. which one will you be using?

Comment: @dawud Currently I'm using thin, but I'd prefer that the init script I'm writing be fairly independent of what web server the deployed app is using.

Comment: Note that an `apache`+ `passenger` stack, for example, won't need an `init` script at all. Anyways, my answer to your `init` question is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate which package contains a file using:

```
# apt-file search /etc/init.d/mountnfs.sh
initscripts: /etc/init.d/mountnfs.sh
```

Check if it is installed:

```
# dpkg -L initscripts | grep /mountnfs.sh
/etc/init.d/mountnfs.sh
```

The LSB header of that file is informative:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mountnfs
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:
# Should-Start:      $network $portmap nfs-common  udev-mtab
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Wait for network file systems to be mounted
# Description:       Network file systems are mounted by
#                    /etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs in the background
#                    when interfaces are brought up; this script waits
#                    for them to be mounted before carrying on.
### END INIT INFO
```

So if you don't use any NFS mount point, you can safely ignore that comment

Comment: Ah, okay. If that's all it is I'm not sure why that warning is included in the skeleton file, but I guess it doesn't really matter in my case.